# Alignment issue in the achievements dialog box

Tags: feature-request, design, achievements-dialog

There is an alignment issue in the achievements dialog box. The privilege icon is not aligned with the reputation score and badge icons.

Can the privilege icon be aligned with others in the achievements dialog?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: achievements dialog]